# Why can't I open a character special file created on my ext4 partition?

Tags: character-special-files

As a test, I did `sudo mknod test c 5 2` in my Downloads folder, which had the effect of creating a file like `/dev/ptmx`. However, `cat test` gives me `No such file or directory`. However, `sudo mknod /dev/test c 5 2` and subsequently `cat /dev/test` works as expected. So, why is there a difference? I don't have a separate home partition and my root is not mounted with `nodev`.

I do not seem to have this problem with MacOS.

Comment: @dirkt (a) the question already says, "is not mounted with `nodev`", and (b) the behavior seems reproducible unless you're suggesting that it works fine when you try it.